# How to query rules in a TypeDB database?

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

In my schema I think I defined this `rule`:

```
define rule transitive-hierarchy-rule:
when {
(before: $a, after: $b) isa hierarchy;
(before: $b, after: $c) isa hierarchy;
} then {
(before: $a, after: $c) isa hierarchy;
};
```

Notice from the [documentation](https://docs.vaticle.com/docs/schema/rules):

> "facts defined via rules are not stored in the knowledge graph. [...]
> However, by defining the rule in the schema, at query time the extra
> fact will be generated."

Also notice from the [documentation](https://docs.vaticle.com/docs/schema/rules):

> Currently, for a match query to trigger reasoning and obtain
> inferences from rules, you must use a read transaction. We are working
> towards enabling reasoning in write transactions in subsequent
> releases.

However in my query `match (before: $x, after: $y) isa hierarchy` inside a `read` transaction doesn't return the expected results:

```
{ $x iid 0x826e800b8000000000000000 isa task; $y iid 0x826e80048000000000000002 isa task; }
{ $x iid 0x826e800a8000000000000000 isa task; $y iid 0x826e800b8000000000000000 isa task; }
```

The above two results I had *explicity* defined. I was expecting the third result to be *inferred* via the rule.

So I am trying to debug the situation. Could it be possible that I did not define the rule properly?

So question: how do I query more about the rules that have been defined in the database schema?

Answer (score 0):

Have you been sure to turn on inference? The 'infer' option must be turned on for rules to be triggered whilst running queries.

See the infer option for the java client API: https://docs.vaticle.com/docs/client-api/java#options

Comment: How do you do this on the TypeDB console? Edit: Found it: https://docs.vaticle.com/docs/console/console

Comment: Also how do you query the rules that exist in the database? This is important thing to be able to do.

Comment: In Console you can use `database schema DB_NAME` to print the schema, which will contain the rules.